# build RHEL6 kernel on Centos 5?

Tags: centos5, kernel

I have an existing Centos 5.5 box that really needs a couple features available in kernel version 2.6.32 and up.

Is it possible to take a RHEL6 kernel and build it on my Centos 5.5 installation?  I can grab the vanilla kernel from kernel.org, but what I really want is the enterprise linux kernel configuration and settings.

Copying my existing Centos 5.5 config and using it on the modern kernel might not be such a good idea because it won't have settings for some of the new features I am seeking to use (such as TRIM for SSDs).

Would it be possible to use the RHEL6 config since Centos 6 is not yet released?

Answer (score 2):

You can compile the RHEL6 kernel on Centos 5. It is the same as compiling a vanila kernel from kernel.org the only difference would be that you would be you would be using source rpms.

Programs with statically linked libraries would need to be recompiled probably.